# Error opening file C:\Users\MHa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpETnP1i\file6003e2e6664.h5Seurat: 32

Tags: r, shiny, seurat

I've been trying to resolve the 32 error on window 10 for R problem in download a file from a Shiny.R application I am developing. This error has never occurred on a Mac.

I predominantly program in a Mac and have limited understanding of the windows environment. They have 32Gb of memory and over 100Gb free space.

Does anyone know what causes this and how to resolve this Error opening file C:\Users\MHa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpETnP1i\file6003e2e6664.h5Seurat: 32

Cheers,
Kerry

I've tried to change the temp directory, but it didn't change the location.

I cannot seem to find a similar issue, and do not know what else to do.